# One SQL statement that updates two tables

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a SQL script that returns one unique row. I want to update one column in that row and a counter in a different table

I model a kind of a work item queue and when one element is selected from the queue, its state gets set to "executing" but I also want to keep track of how many items of a certain priority have been selected.

Following is the script without the table that is used for counting

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'[Queue]', N'U') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE [Queue]

CREATE TABLE [Queue](
    [ID]        int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Priority]  int NOT NULL default 3,
    [State]     int NOT NULL default 0,
    [Command]   nvarchar(max),    
    [Queued]    datetime2 NOT NULL default GetDate(),
    [Assigned]  datetime2 NULL
) 

INSERT INTO [Queue] ([Command], [Priority], [Queued])    VALUES 
    ('systeminfo', 1, DATEADD(MILLISECOND, -40, GETDATE())),
    ('systeminfo', 2, DATEADD(MILLISECOND, -30, GETDATE())),
    ('systeminfo', 1, DATEADD(MILLISECOND, -20, GETDATE())),
    ('systeminfo', 3, DATEADD(MILLISECOND, -20, GETDATE()))
GO

IF OBJECT_ID(N'Dequeue', N'P') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP PROCEDURE Dequeue
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE Dequeue
AS
    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ

    UPDATE selected
    SET [State] = 1, Assigned = GETDATE()
    OUTPUT inserted.*
    FROM (
        SELECT TOP(1) * 
        FROM [Queue] 
        WHERE [State] = 0 
        ORDER BY [Priority] ASC, [Queued] ASC
    ) selected
```

The update statement in the stored procedure now should also do something like

```
UPDATE [Counter] 
SET [Counter].[Count] = [Counter].[Count] + 1 
WHERE [Counter][Priority] = selected.[Priority]
```

Do I have to temporarily store the selected row in a Temp Table or variable, or is there a more elegant way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use option with variable of type table

```
  DECLARE @Priority TABLE (Priority int)

  UPDATE selected
    SET [State] = 1, Assigned = GETDATE()
    OUTPUT inserted.Priority INTO @Priority(Priority)
    FROM (
          SELECT TOP(1) * 
          FROM [Queue] 
          WHERE [State] = 0 
          ORDER BY [Priority] ASC, [Queued] ASC
          ) selected

 UPDATE c
   SET c.[Count] = ISNULL(c.[Count], 0) + 1
   FROM [Counter] c JOIN @Priority p ON c.[Priority] = p.[Priority]
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding a trigger to the Queue table thad runs your update on the Counter table?

Comment: Sounds like a nice idea. 
But I get 
Msg 334, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Dequeue,
The target table 'Queue' of the DML statement cannot have any enabled triggers if the statement contains an OUTPUT clause without INTO clause.

Comment: Interesting, I'm not familiar enough with stored procedures to help with that error. Best of luck.